# How to define a correct index by constructing simple pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following python dictionary:

`sdata ={'Ohio': 35000, 'Oregon': 16000, 'Texas': 71000, 'Utah': 5000}`

Suppose I want to create pandas Series from this dictionary. For some reasons, I want to construct the Series with additional columns:

```
states = ['California', 'Damascus','Ohio', 'Oregon', 'Texas','Regensburg', 'Munich']
obj4 = pd.Series(sdata, index=states)
obj4
```

And the output will be:

```
California        NaN
Damascus          NaN
Ohio          35000.0
Oregon        16000.0
Texas         71000.0
Regensburg        NaN
Munich            NaN
dtype: float64
```

In this case, 3 values found in sdata were placed in the appropriate locations, but since **no** value for `California`, `Damascus`, `Regensburg`, and `Munich` were found, they appears as `NaN`.
In other words, an index without corresponding value in `sdata` will appear as `NaN`.

However, it does not work when I am trying to create Series from a list:

```
labels = ['Covid', 'Delta', 'Omicron', 'Mu']
obj2 = pd.Series([1.5, -2.5, 0], index=labels) 
obj2
```

The error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-3f289c72627f> in <module>()
      1 # use the above created index object as an index in this Serie
----> 2 obj2 = pd.Series([1.5, -2.5, 0], index=labels)
      3 obj2

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    312                     if len(index) != len(data):
    313                         raise ValueError(
--> 314                             f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
    315                             f"index implies {len(index)}."
    316                         )

ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 4.
```

I did not understand why I get this message error although it is allowed to create Series with `NaN` values as in the first case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#series) explain the process for pandas Series creation; if it is a list/ndarray-like object, the length of the index must match the length of the values in the list; for a dictionary, the keys are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Series` only with dictionary and then add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
obj4 = pd.Series(sdata).reindex(states)
```

If create by list is necessary same length of index like data list first, e.g. for length of `3` is filtered first 3 values of list `labels`:

```
labels = ['Covid', 'Delta', 'Omicron', 'Mu']
obj2 = pd.Series([1.5, -2.5, 0], index=labels[:3]).reindex(labels)
```